# WordPress - custom user flow registration approval

Tags: forms, user-registration

I'm working on a custom user login and regitration flow. I need to give the users the ability to register and after the registration is completed, they will need to wait for account approval, is there any wordpress function or hook I can use to achive this?

Comment: That's sort of a broad goal with several different possible approaches - you will likely use many WordPress hooks and functions in the course of implementing it. Could you be a little more specific about your approach/what you're looking for?

Comment: I need to find the right hooks that will give me the ability to send new registered users an email only if the account is approved, the most important thing is that I need to avoid that these users can login until the account is approved. At the moment I've added a custom meta field and I want to use it for the check if an user account is approved or not

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.